# Changing brightness in Samsung N140 Plus

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, samsung

How to change screen/backlight brightness on Samsung N140 Plus? I tried xbacklight, but is says it can't see a backlighted out. The install is out-of-box Ubuntu 10.10 desktop. So how do I change the brightness?

Comment: I had this problem, but it has been fixed with some recent updates. This is on NC110.

Answer (score 5):

An Italian user, Voria, is maintaining a ppa with all the patches needed to make Ubuntu fully working on Samsung laptops. [Here](http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=296) you can find more details about this ppa and packages in it. I have successfully applied this on a Samsung R519.
In particular `samsung-backlight` and `samsung-tools` are most important packages to have everything working (brightness, wireless switch, external monitor, touchpad switch and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Try keep pressed the **blue Fn Key** while pressing the Up ( or Down ) arrow.
It works for me on my Samsung Notebook (R710)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

upgrade to 12.04 and it works and the wifi works too!
the only problem i had was the brightness was too low to start with. this was fixed by going into BIOS at start up and udjusting brightness with the keys whilst in BOIS. then load OS and the brightest setting is now alot brighter
hope this helps